# For $a$, $b$, $c$ the sides of a triangle, show $\sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt{bc}\,bc}{a(a+b+c)(b+c-a)}\geq1$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

> Let $a,b,c$ be the side lengths of a triangle. How to prove the following inequality?
>   $$\frac{\sqrt{bc}\,bc}{a(a+b+c)(b+c-a)}+\frac{\sqrt{ac}\,ac}{b(a+b+c)(a+c-b)}+\frac{\sqrt{ab}\,ab}{c(a+b+c)(a+b-c)}\geq1$$

Via some numerical experiment and graphing techniques, I am sure it is true. Could we use AM-GM?

My goal is to find an analytic/conventional proof of this inequality. I have tried AM-GM, but it didn't work. Since it is a homogeneous function with degree 0, WLOG, let $a=1.$ Then I plotted the LHS of this inequality using the Maple command "plot3d" which clearly shows that the LHS ≥ 1.

Comment: Would you like to share what you have tried/thought of so far? (And where you got stuck so we can help you)

Comment: @sliang668 I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: *"Via some numerical experiment and graphing techniques, I am sure it is true."* ... Does this mean that the inequality is a *conjecture*? Otherwise, why would there be any doubt about its truth?

Comment: My goal is to find an analytic/conventional proof of this inequality. I have tried AM-GM, but it didn't work. Since it is a homogeneous function with degree 0, WLOG, let a=1. Then I plotted the LHS of this inequality using the Maple command "plot3d" which clearly shows that the LHS ≥ 1.

Comment: @sliang668.- You are correct, the inequality is true. There are trios of real numbers $(a, b, c)$ such that they do not satisfy the inequality but in such cases it is not possible to construct a triangle with them. I have ruled out any possibility within my grasp and am convinced that there are no counterexamples. I leave your problem because I can not solve it (I trust that Michael Rozenberg can solve it).

Comment: @Piquito Thank you. I trust Michael Rozenberg too.

Comment: @sliang668 Show please, how exactly you used AM-GM and you'll get my solution immediately.

Answer (score 1):

$\require{begingroup} \begingroup$
$\def\f#1#2#3{\frac{#2#3\sqrt{#2#3}}{#1(#1+#2+#3)(-#1+#2+#3)}}$

\begin{align}
\f abc+\f bca+\f cab 
&\ge 1
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

By AM-GM

\begin{align}
&\f abc+\f bca
+\f cab 
\\
&\ge
3\sqrt[3]{
\f abc\cdot\f bca\cdot\f cab
}
\tag{2}\label{2}
\\
&=
3\sqrt[3]{
\frac{(abc)^2}{
(a+b+c)^3(-a+b+c)(a-b+c)(a+b-c)
}
}
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Let $\rho$, $r$ and $R$
be the semiperimeter, inradius and circumradius of corresponding triangle.

Then we can rewrite \eqref{3} as

\begin{align}
&3\sqrt[3]{
\frac{(4\rho r R)^2}{
16(2\rho)^2\rho(\rho-a)(\rho-b)(\rho-c)}}
\tag{4}\label{4}
\\
&=
3\sqrt[3]{
\frac{(\rho r R)^2}{
(2\rho)^2\rho^2r^2
}
}
=3\sqrt[3]{\frac{R^2}{4\rho^2}}
=\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4(\rho/R)^2}}
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

All of the above statements equally hold for a similar normalized triangle, 
scaled by $\tfrac1R$,
so let $u=\rho/R$ and $v=r/R$. 
This parameterization is useful, 
since all possible valid triangular shapes
are uniquely defined by a pair $v,u$ for all $v\in[0,\tfrac12]$.
Also, for any given $v$ all the valid values of $u$ 
are located between

\begin{align}
u_{\min}&=\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2-2\sqrt{(1-2\,v)^3}}
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
u_{\max}&=\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2+2\sqrt{(1-2\,v)^3}}
\tag{7}\label{7}
\end{align}

and of course, $u_{\max}\ge u_{\min}$ for all valid values of $v$.

So,

\begin{align}
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4(\rho/R)^2}}
&=
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4\,u^2}}
\ge
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4\,u_{\max}(v)^2}}
\ge
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4\,\Big(\displaystyle\max_{v\in[0,\tfrac12]}u_{\max}(v)\Big)^2}}
\tag{8}\label{8}
.
\end{align}

Note that $u_{\max}(v)$ is increasing on $v=[0,\tfrac12]$
and

\begin{align}
\max_{v\in\Big[0,\tfrac12\Big]}u_{\max}(v)
&=
u_{\max}(\tfrac12)
=\tfrac32\,\sqrt3
\tag{9}\label{9}
,
\end{align}

so we have

\begin{align}
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4\,\Big(\displaystyle\max_{v\in[0,\tfrac12]}u_{\max}(v)\Big)^2}}
&=
\frac{3}{\sqrt[3]{4\,\Big(\tfrac32\,\sqrt3\Big)^2}}
=1
\tag{10}\label{10}
,
\end{align}

and the proof is complete.

---

It looks like that some comment on the Eqns \eqref{6}, \eqref{7} is due.
As it was mentioned in the comments, one reference can be found in,
for example, p.2, Eqs.(2),(3) in Mitrinovic, D.S., Pecaric, J. and Volenec, V., 1989. Recent advances in geometric inequalities (Vol. 28). Brill Archive.
More references can be found there, one is as old as of 1890-1891.
But basically, it follows from well-known expressions:

\begin{align}
a_2&=a+b+c=2\rho
\tag{11}\label{11}
,\\
a_1&=ab+bc+ca=\rho^2+r^2+4rR
\tag{12}\label{12}
,\\
a_0&=abc=4\rho r R
\tag{13}\label{13}
\end{align}
and hence, the roots of this cubic equation
\begin{align}
x^3-a_2 x^2+a_1 x-a_0&=0
\tag{14}\label{14}
\end{align}
are the three side length $a,b,c$ of the triangle
with given $\rho,r$ and $R$.

Roots of \eqref{14} are all real, when its discriminant

\begin{align}
\Delta(1,-a_2,a_1,-a_0)&=
18\,a_2\,a_1\,a_0-4\,a_2^3\,a_0+a_2^2\,a_1^2-4\,a_1^3-27\,a_0^2
\\
&=
-4\,r^2\,(\rho^4
-(4\,R\,(5\,r+R)-2\,r^2)\,\rho^2+r\,(r+4\,R)^3)
\ge 0
\tag{15}\label{15}
,
\end{align}
and equations \eqref{6}, \eqref{7} follow.

$\endgroup$

Comment: Great solution! But I am not familiar with (6) and (7). Could you tell me the references? Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @sliang668: For example, p.2, Eqs.(2),(3) in

Mitrinovic, D.S., Pecaric, J. and Volenec, V., 1989. Recent advances in geometric inequalities (Vol. 28). Brill Archive.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I will read it soon.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that (see @g.kov's result)
$$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{(abc)^2}{(a+b+c)^3(a+b-c)(b+c-a)(c+a-b)}} \ge 1.$$
By using Ravi Substitution $a = x + y, b = y+z, c = z + x$ for $x, y, z > 0$, the inequality becomes
$$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{[(x+y)(y+z)(z+x)]^2}{64(x+y+z)^3xyz}} \ge 1.$$
Let $p = x+y+z, q = xy + yz + zx, r = xyz$. The inequality becomes
$$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{(pq - r)^2}{64p^3 r}} \ge 1.$$
Since $pq \ge 9r$ and $q^2 \ge 3pr$, we have
$$3\sqrt[3]{\frac{(pq - r)^2}{64p^3 r}} \ge 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{(pq - \frac{pq}{9})^2}{64p^2q^2/3}} = 1.$$
We are done.