# Prove $\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b} +\frac{81abc}{4(a+b+c)^2} \geqq \frac{7}{4} (a+b+c)$

Tags: inequality, symmetric-polynomials, sum-of-squares-method, buffalo-way

For $a,b,c>0$. Prove that$:$
$$\frac{ab}{c}+\frac{bc}{a}+\frac{ca}{b} +\frac{81abc}{4(a+b+c)^2} \geqq \frac{7}{4} (a+b+c)$$

**My proof:**

We have$:$ $$\text{LHS}-\text{RHS} =\frac{g(a,b,c)}{4abc(a+b+c)^2} \geqq 0$$

Where
$g(a,b,c) =\frac{1}{16} \left( a+b \right) ^{2} \left( 2\,a+2\,b-c \right) ^{2} \left( 
a+b-2\,c \right) ^{2}$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+\frac{1}{64} \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \cdot \Big[ \left( 2\,c-a-b \right) ^{3} \left( 
119\,a+119\,b+30\,c \right)$

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+\left( a+b-2\,c \right) ^{2} \left( 343\,{a}^{2}+346\,ab+343\,{b}^{2}
 \right) $

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+24\, \left( 2\,c-a-b \right)  \left( a+b \right)  \left( 16\,{a}^{2}+a
b+16\,{b}^{2} \right) $

$\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,+36\, \left( 4\,{a}^{2}-5\,ab+4\,{b}^{2} \right)  \left( a+b \right) ^{
2} \Big] \geqq 0$

which is clearly true for $c=\max\{a,b,c\}$

I wish to see another proof without $uvw$! Thanks for a real lot!

You can see also [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2111079p15282018).

Comment: Where you wrote $\text{LHS-RHS},$ I wonder if you meant $\text{LHS}-\text{RHS}$, i.e. a minus sign rather than a hyphen? Notice the difference: $$ \begin{align} & \text{LHS-RHS} \\ & {\text{LHS}} - \text{RHS} \end{align} $$ I looked at your MathJax code and it's clear that it was written by one of those software packages that do the code for you. The one you used makes the code look like something written by a lunatic.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Actually I only use Maple to factor, not by using code.

Comment: I don't understand your last comment; mine was about typesetting. Did you actually intend a minus sign rather than a hyphen?

Comment: @MichaelHardy It's $LHS-RHS$

Comment: Why do you insist (as it seems from your edits) that there word "where" should have a capital rather than a lower-case initial "W" in the middle of a sentence, and also on the kind of formatting you've done with sum in five lines at the end?

Comment: @MichaelHardy Haha, no matter at all, I only edit because I prefer it more! Sorry!

Comment: You have all those "plus" signs vertically aligned with the "equals" sign above them, and you have them as close to the expressions to their right as if they were unary rather than binary operations, thus: $$ \begin{align} & 1+2+3 \\ & {+4}+5+6 \\ \text{versus this:} \\ & 1+2+3 \\ & {} + 4+5+6  \end{align} $$

Comment: @tthnew Let $a=x_1^2, b = x_2^2, c = x_3^2$. Then $(x_1^2+x_2^2)g(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$ may be a SOS of polynomials. (But $g(x_1^2, x_2^2, x_3^2)$ may not be a SOS of polynomials).

Comment: @RiverLi  how you know that$?$ By the way$,$ sometimes from pqr technique form we can get in to SOS.

Comment: @tthnew  I just tried and found it. Your SOS is not standard since you need to assume something like $c = \max(a,b,c)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Also, we can use the $uvw$'s technique.

Indeed, let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, we need to prove that
$$\frac{9v^4-6uw^3}{w^3}+\frac{81w^3}{36u^2}\geq\frac{21u}{4}$$ or
$$w^6-5u^3w^3+4u^2v^4\geq0,$$ which is obviously true by $uvw$, which you don't want.

But we can use the following way.

$$(a-b)^2(a-c)^2(b-c)^2\geq0$$ it's $$3u^2v^4-4v^6-4u^3w^3+6uv^2w^3-w^6\geq0,$$ which gives
$$3uv^2-2u^3-2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}\leq w^3\leq3uv^2-2u^3+2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}.$$
But for proving $w^6-5u^3w^3+4u^2v^4\geq0$ it's enough to prove that
$$w^3\leq\frac{5u^3-\sqrt{25u^6-16u^2v^4}}{2},$$ for which it's enough to prove that
$$3uv^2-2u^3+2\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}\leq\frac{5u^3-\sqrt{25u^6-16u^2v^4}}{2}$$ or
$$9u^3-6uv^2-4\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}\geq\sqrt{25u^6-16u^2v^4}.$$
But by AM-GM
$$9u^3-6uv^2=3u^3+6u(u^2-v^2)\geq6u^2\sqrt{u^2-v^2}\geq4\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}.$$
Id est, it's enough to prove that:
$$\left(9u^3-6uv^2-4\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}\right)^2\geq25u^6-16u^2v^4$$ or
$$18u^6-39u^4v^2+25u^2v^4-4v^6\geq6u(3u^2-2v^2)\sqrt{(u^2-v^2)^3}$$ or
$$18u^4-21u^2v^2+4v^4\geq6u(3u^2-2v^2)\sqrt{u^2-v^2}$$ and since $$18u^4-21u^2v^2+4v^4=3(u^2-v^2)(6u^2-v^2)+v^4>0,$$ we need to prove that
$$(18u^4-21u^2v^2+4v^4)^2\geq36u^2(3u^2-2v^2)^2(u^2-v^2)$$ or
$$(3u^2-4v^2)^2\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

[image: solution]

here you go                              .

Comment: Please edit and use 
[MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) 
to properly format math expressions instead of posting ugly pictures.

Answer (score 1):

I found a proof by Titu's Lemma$:$

Let $$\text{LHS} -\text{RHS} \equiv \frac{g(a,b,c)}{4abc(a+b+c)^2}$$

But we have

\begin{align*} g(a,\,b,\,c) &=\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{cyc} c^2(a+b-5c)^2 (a-b)^2-9(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2 \\&\geq \frac{1}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)} \Big[\sum\limits_{cyc} c^2(a+b-5c)(a-b)\Big]^2-9(a-b)^2(b-c)^2(c-a)^2\\&={\frac { \left( a-b \right) ^{2} \left( b-c \right) ^{2} \left( c-a
 \right) ^{2} \left( 7\,{a}^{2}+50\,ab+50\,ac+7\,{b}^{2}+50\,bc+7\,{c}
^{2} \right) }{2\,(a^2+b^2+c^2)}} \geq 0\end{align*}

So we are done.

Answer (score 0):

Here $a,b,c$ replaced for $x,y,z$ for convenience.

For $x,y,z>0$ prove that

\begin{align}
\frac{xy}z+\frac{yz}x+\frac{zx}y+
\frac{81xyz}{4(x+y+z)^2}
&\ge
\tfrac74(x+y+z)
\tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align}

Using [Ravi substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution),

\begin{align} 
x&=\rho-a
,\quad
y=\rho-b
,\quad
z=\rho-c
,
\end{align}

the inequality \eqref{1} transforms
(omitting lengthy, but straightforward details) into equivalent 
inequality

\begin{align} 
85\,r^2+32\,r\,R+64\,R^2
-15\,\rho^2
&\ge 0
\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}

in terms of the semiperimeter $\rho$,
inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$ 
of some valid triangle with the side lengths

\begin{align} 
a&=y+z
,\quad
b=z+x
,\quad
c=x+y
.
\end{align}

Dividing \eqref{2} by $R^2$, we get

\begin{align} 
85\,v^2+32\,v+64
-15\,u^2
&\ge 0
\tag{3}\label{3}
,
\end{align}
where $u=\rho/R$, $v=r/R$.

Now all we have to do is to check \eqref{3}
for all valid triangles, that means for all $v\in[0,\tfrac12]$
and $u(v)\in[u_{\min}(v),u_{\max}(v)]$.

Obviously,
\begin{align} 
85\,v^2+32\,v+64
-15\,u^2
&\ge 
85\,v^2+32\,v+64
-15\,u_{\max}(v)^2
\tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align}
[where](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3656200/122782)

\begin{align}
u_{\max}&=\sqrt{27-(5-v)^2+2\sqrt{(1-2\,v)^3}}
\tag{5}\label{5}
,
\end{align}

and we have \eqref{1} equivalent to

\begin{align}
50v^2-59v+17-15\sqrt{(1-2v)^3}
&\ge 0
\tag{6}\label{6}
,\\
(50v^2-59v+17)^2-15^2((1-2v)^3)
&\ge 0
\tag{7}\label{7}
,\\
(25v-8)^2(1-2v)^2
&\ge 0
\tag{8}\label{8}
,
\end{align}
which holds for all values of $v\in[0,\tfrac12]$,
that is for all valid triangles with the side lengths given by
\eqref{2} and hence, 
\eqref{1} is true
for all real $x,y,z$.

Answer (score 0):

BW helps!

Let $a\leq b\leq c$, $b=a+u$ and $c=a+u+v.$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$9(u^2+uv+v^2)a^4+3(14u^3+21u^2v+3uv^2-2v^3)a^2+$$
$$+(73u^4+146u^3v+66u^2v^2-7uv^3+v^4)a^2+$$
$$+u(56u^4+140u^3v+114u^2v^2+31uv^3+v^4)a+$$
$$+4u^2(2u^2+3uv+v^2)^2\geq0,$$
for which it's enough to prove that:
$$4(u^2+uv+v^2)(73u^4+146u^3v+66u^2v^2-7uv^3+v^4)\geq(14u^3+21u^2v+3uv^2-2v^3)^2$$ or
$$292u^6+876u^5v-85u^4v^2+610u^3v^3+391u^2v^4+8uv^5+20v^6\geq0,$$ which is obvious.